# What is the difference between using a gem like devise_token_auth and devise_jwt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt, devise-token-auth, devise-jwt

I have a rails api only application that I want to use devise for the authentication. I came across this decision and I want to know which one is better. Would it make sense for a high volume web application to use something like `devise_token_auth` or `devise_jwt`. I do understand that devise_jwt uses JSON Web Tokens but it has proved to be difficult when implementing OAuth.

I would switch to devise_token_auth but I just want to understand if it is actually better or worse than jwt as a form of authentication.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!